# How to display/show more... special text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have some text like simple

```
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
    ....
```

i want make it like (2 line at one)

```
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
more...
```

when i click more... 2 line show, this work repeat until all data showed
How can i do that, any idea? thanks

Update code: i have data from json, but i store it into variable like: http://jsfiddle.net/jWsJP/

Comment: Please make some sort of effort... also at least provide complete HTML. Is the `more...` in the `<ul>`? Is it another `<li>`?

Comment: @all i just update simple code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a quick fiddle for you : http://jsfiddle.net/A4UU5/1/

Start by hiding with css all your li with `display:none;`.

---

**Edit:** After Bram Vanroy comment, you are better hiding them with JS like that :

```
$('ul').find('li').hide()
```

---

Then save some usefull var that you can change later if you wish :

```
var intShow = 2; //Number of elements you show on click
var elLength = $('ul').children().length; //number of li
var current= 1; //start position based on a 0 index
```

Then create a function that with show li :

```
function showItems(){
    for(var i=0; i <= current; i++){
        $('ul').find('li').eq(i).show();
    }
}
```

Now just add the click binding that will increment the current  index :

```
$('#more').click(function(){
    current += intShow;

    if(current >= elLength){
        current = elLength - 1;
        $(this).remove(); //It remove the button when all li are shown
    }

    showItems();
})
```

that's it!

Comment: You'd better hide the li's with JS otherwise people who have JS disabled will see no items at all and have no option to show them. And don't forget semicolons!

Comment: True, I always for those kind of people, they are bad people! :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8SC4/1) I made. Best practices such as variables are not included because I just don't have the time right now and I don't see a quick way where they could really be handy.

jQuery

```
$("li").hide();
$("li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(2)").show();

$("button").click(function() {
    $("li:visible:last").next().show("fast", function() {
        $(this).next().show(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":last-child")) {
                $("p").text("All items shown");
                $("button").remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>

<button>MOAR</button>
<p></p>
```

Comment: thanks u. it's hard to custom like show 3 or 4 when click button :)

Answer (score 0):

Do like this...

HTML:

```
<div class="expandable reduced">   
     <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</div>
<a class="expand">more...</a>
```

CSS:

```
.reduced {
    height: 40px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".expand").click(function(event){
    $(".expandable").toggleClass("reduced");
    $(this).remove(); // better practice for toggle: change innerHtml to reduce/more
});
```